# TCP send and recieve packets

Tags: python, python-3.x, networking, tcp, network-programming

I'm preparing for robotics competition. Here is my task:

> Passenger pick-up and drop-off points are transmitted to the robots in
>   unicast form over the TCP protocol using the wireless IEEE 802.11 b /
>   g / n communication standard. The robot **connects to the listening
>   server at 192.168.1.100:9999**.

To realize it I'm trying the following python code:

```
import socket

TCP_IP = '192.168.1.100'
TCP_PORT = 9999
BUFFER_SIZE = 1024

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
data = s.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
s.close()

print "received data:", data
```

The problem is, I'm not sure if it is this code is the right path(receiving packets) and I could not make a test.

It would be awesome to know if there are any **TCP packet senders** **to specific IP and port**. In this way, I can test whether I'm recieving or not. Suggest considering my task, please.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Simple tcp receiver may look like this in python 3:

```
import socket

def receiver_tcp(tcp_ip, tcp_port, echo=True, buffer_size=4096):

    with socket.socket(
            socket.AF_INET,  # Internet
            socket.SOCK_STREAM  # TCP
            ) as sock:
        sock.bind((tcp_ip, tcp_port))
        # listening forever
        while True:
            sock.listen()
            conn, addr = sock.accept()
            answer = ''
            # getting and decoding message
            while True:
                answer_part = conn.recv(buffer_size).decode('UTF-8')
                if not answer_part:
                    conn.close()
                    break
                answer += answer_part
            # logging to console
            if echo:
                print(answer)
```

Simple tcp sender may look like this:

```
import socket

def sender_tcp(message, tcp_ip, tcp_port):

    with socket.socket(
            socket.AF_INET,  # Internet
            socket.SOCK_STREAM  # TCP
            ) as sock:
        sock.connect((tcp_ip, tcp_port))
        sock.send(message.encode('UTF-8'))
```

You can run receiver and sender on the same computer in different threads in python or use two computers.